# Cordova : after converting my application to android, I am not able to Login

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I am converting my web application to android mob application using apache cordova, after converting mob app is successfully Installed in my mobile phone. Now I am not able to Login in cordova Mobile app. but its working fine in browser.

when i try to login Its showing Errors like this :

**Mixed Content: The page at was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{}, "lazyUpdate":null,"headers":
 {}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://****/xyz
 _api/api/v0/Authenticate","ok":false,"name": 
"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://***/xyz 
/api/v0/Authenticate: 0 Unknown Error","error": {"isTrusted":true}}
```

I did some changes in config.xml file by adding this code :

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" >
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
</platform>
```

please help to solve this Issue. Thank you